# Can't define dataframe after import csv using tkinter

Tags: python, pandas, user-interface, tkinter

I am a new user in Tkinter.

I have  buttons for ( import CSV and prediction).
I need the CSV file I just imported to be processed (do predict) using the prediction button.
This is my code :

```
  import tkinter as tk
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
    from tkinter import filedialog
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
    from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
    
class NewprojectApp:
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        # build ui
        main_window = ttk.Frame(master)
        label_1 = ttk.Label(main_window)
        label_1.config(font='{sans } 12 {bold}', justify='center', padding='100', text='PREDIKSI IHSG BBCA.JK')
        label_1.pack(side='top')
        button_1 = ttk.Button(main_window)
        button_1.config(text='Import CSV', command = self.getCSV)
        button_1.place(anchor='nw', relx='0.14', rely='0.66', x='0', y='0')
        button_2 = ttk.Button(main_window)
        button_2.config(text='Prediksi', command = self.prediksi)
        button_2.place(anchor='nw', relwidth='0.31', relx='0.55', rely='0.66', x='0', y='0')
        main_window.config(height='200', width='200')
        main_window.pack(side='top')

        # Main widget
        self.mainwindow = main_window
        

    def run(self):
        self.mainwindow.mainloop()
        
    def getCSV(self):
        global df
        
        import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        df = pd.read_csv(import_file_path, usecols=['Date','Open'])
        df.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.Date , format = '%Y-%m-%d')
        df.index = df.timestamp
        df.drop('Date',axis = 1, inplace = True)
        df.fillna(df.mean(),inplace=True)
        df_transform = np.log(df)
        
        
    def prediksi(self):
        split_point = round(len(df_transform)* 90/100)
        data_train, data_validation = df_transform[0:split_point], df_transform[split_point:]
        history = [x for x in data_train['Open']]
        predictions = list()
        for t in range(len(data_validation)):
            model = ARIMA(history, order=(1,1,1))
            model_fit = model.fit(trend='c', disp=0)
            output = model_fit.forecast()
            yhat = output[0]
            predictions.append(yhat)
            obs = data_validation['Open'][t]
            history.append(obs)
            print('predicted=%.4f, expected=%.4f' % (np.exp(yhat), np.exp(obs)))
        error = mean_squared_error(np.exp(data_validation['Open']),np.exp(predictions))
        print('Test MSE: %.3f' % error)
    
        
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = NewprojectApp(root)
    app.run()
```

ERROR I am getting says that my data is not defined.
Provide some information on this.
Above is the full code.

Comment: `df_transform` is a local variable inside `getCSV()` and cannot be accessed inside `prediksi()`.

Comment: so can i make it to the global ?

Comment: Better use instance variable `self.df_transform` instead of global variable.  Same for `df`.